# finding line integral with potential function

Tags: vector-fields, line-integrals

Evaluate the line integral

$$
\int_C (\ln y) e^{-x} \,dx - \dfrac{e^{-x}}{y}\,dy + z\,dz
$$

where C is the curve parametrized by $r(t)=(t-1)i+e^{t^4}j+(t^2+1)k$ for $0\leq t\leq 1$

I know that the potential function is $$f(x, y, z) = -e^{-x}\ln y + \frac{z^2}{2} + C$$ but exactly how would I use that to evaluate the line integral?

Comment: What course is this from? The identical integral was asked earlier today. I'll find the link.

Comment: Would 1/2 be the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much like an ordinary real integral.  The potential function takes the place of the antiderivative; if the the path goes from $A$ to $B$ then the integral is
$$f(B)-f(A)\ .$$
In this case $A$ is $r(0)$ and $B$ is $r(1)$.  Can you do the calculations?

Comment: So I just do f(1,1,1)-f(0,0,0)?

Comment: I don't think $r(0)$ is $(0,0,0)$ is it?  Look at the formula for $r(t)$.

Comment: Whoops I got r(0)=-i+j+k and r(1)=ej+2k. So exactly what would I do with that?

Comment: Now you have to calculate $f(B)-f(A)$.  You know $f$, you know $B$, you know $A$, so you should not have any difficulty with this.

Comment: Just to check, so f(0,e,2)-f(-1,1,1) will give the answer?

Comment: ^1/5 as answer, if so?

Comment: ^I mean 1/2 is answer?